# Using simple, MathJax-compatible TeX to put enclose a matrix in braces

Tags: matrices, braces, online, mathjax

I was trying to explain the identity matrix over at [Math StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/328853/12952) and I wound up using the following.

```
$${\bf I_n} = \underbrace{
                \left.\left( 
                      \begin{array}{ccccc}
                             1&0&0&\cdots &0\\
                             0&1&0&\cdots &0\\
                             0&0&1&\cdots &0\\
                             \vdots&&&\ddots&\\
                             0&0&0&\cdots &1
                      \end{array}
                \right)\right\}
              }_{n\text{ columns}} 
              \,n\text{ rows}
$$
```

It came out alright, but not quite what I wanted:

[image: Identity Matrix]

I'd like to be able to move the ends of the underbrace inside the parenthesis without having it turn into this:

[image: Identity Matrix 2]

Now, I see there are a couple of similar questions on here (examples: [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48572/6537) [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44330/6537)) which deal with the same issue.  However, all of them use a bunch of fancy stuff which I can't use in online forum TeX.

> Is there a way to enclose a matrix in braces using only commands available in MathJax?

I am not sure exactly which commands these are, but I am guessing a good rule of thumb would be the simplest commands possible.

Comment: Related: [Curly brackets around a table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86792)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is how I would do it in regular LaTeX (though I would use `\[...\]` to enclose display math):

```
$$\mathbf{I}_n = \left.\left( 
                  \vphantom{\begin{array}{c}1\\1\\1\\1\\1\end{array}}
                  \smash{\underbrace{
                      \begin{array}{ccccc}
                             1&0&0&\cdots &0\\
                             0&1&0&\cdots &0\\
                             0&0&1&\cdots &0\\
                             \vdots&&&\ddots&\\
                             0&0&0&\cdots &1
                      \end{array}
                      }_{n\text{ columns}}}
              \right)\right\}
              \,n\text{ rows}
$$
```

The `\vphantom` line creates a box whose height is equal to an nx1 array of 1's.  The `\smash` around your matrix typesets the matrix (including the underbrace) but makes its height and depth zero.  Put these together and you have a box which includes the underbrace, but whose width and height are equal to that of the matrix without the underbrace.

[image: sample code output]

See ["A complement to `\smash`, `\llap`, and `\rlap`" by Alexander R. Perlis in *TUGBoat*](http://math.arizona.edu/~aprl/publications/mathclap/perlis_mathclap_24Jun2003.pdf) for more on all of these commands and also `\mathclap`.

I pasted it into the [MathJax demo page](http://www.mathjax.org/demos/) too and it seems to work.

Comment: It should be `\mathbf{I}_{n}`, of course: the `n` shouldn't be bold and `\bf` is deprecated; `\mathbf` works in MathJax too.

Comment: @egreg: thanks.  I was focusing on the alignment and I didn't notice that.  fixed.