How does one design a new extensible delimiter that extends in perpendicular directions?
I have not begun yet to look at code samples to try to figure this out, so I'm really at the beginning stage.  As such, I don't have any MWE to post (yet), but it is a general question.  What exactly is involved in creating new extensible delimiters on the LaTeX (or possibly this will require TeX) end?
Here is the critical part that I think warrants a new question.  I'd like to create a bracket that extends horizontally and vertically (that is, along one side and either the top or bottom) and joins in the common corner.  So its innards will me matrix-like, although row and column structures are included in that. It seems reasonable that this should be possible since LaTeX has extensible overbrackets and underbrackets, but I really don't know.  I assume there will need to be one symbol for the corner, one each for the opposite ends of the two perpendiculars, and both vertical and horizontal extensible "middle" sections.  I've become familiar enough with FontLab and FontForge to believe that I can make the necessary symbols, but I don't know what is involved in connecting the various parts together smoothly.
If someone can point me to what to read and where to find it, that may be all I need.  I have not been able to find very much about this (surprisingly) in this forum and I don't know where this would be in the documentation because I have a feeling this is going to involve low-level coding.
Also, I have a feeling that this can be done easily enough with TikZ, possibly even with existing fonts, but I'm not sure that would be the appropriate way to go.  I don't have an aversion to low-level programming, I just don't know where to find the relevant documentation.
Here is a sketch of one of the brackets, but please remember that I'll need more than one type, so I am looking for a general solution.


It depends on what you want to achieve. Maybe the nicematrix package could be an approach.

@Jasper Habicht Actually, nicematrix was the first thing I looked at.  I cannot see where it has this functionality.  I believe that getting the look I'm shooting for is going to involve creating the symbols at the font level (I actually need more than one type of this bracket) and I don't think nicematrix will easily incorporate that.  Plus, it is built on top of TikZ, which something tells me I should avoid if possible.  maybe I am wrong about that last part.

Hm, you are right, it does not come with a version with braces, although it has commands such as \OverBrace. Well, it essentially creates a box and attaches the braces to this box which could be a sensible way to so what you want. You should be able to do this in some other way as well (see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44333/47927). But I don't even know whether creating a box is the right approach here, since it is unclear to me how the result should look like and what you want to wrap inside.

Can you provide a sketch of the desired result?

extensible brackets are normally not defined in tex at all but are a feature of the font. so you could define a new font with additional delimiters (see for example the yhfonts which do exactly this) or as you say you could not use fonts at all and draw the delimiters using tikz or pstricks etc

@David Carlisle Yes, I have seen these glyphs in fonts, but how does the font know how to assemble them from the various parts and extend them as necessary? That is what I had assumed was TeX, but I guess not.

@egreg Sketch added.

for classic tex fonts it's a feature of the tfm format as set up (usually) by metafont. For opentype fots nof luatex/xetex then it's a feature of the MATH opentype table that defines a math font, which you can see in fontforge and other font tools. It is not really on topic here as it's not tex specific, an opentype font with stretch delimiters will stretch them in microsoft word or in a web browser via mathml etc

@David Carlisle I can generate fonts for either case, of course, but I will probably go the OpenType route because I'm trying to gravitate toward Unicode and use XeTeX exclusively these days.  But this is a math-specific application to be sure, so will the OpenType functionality work in a (Xe,Lua)-TeX environment?  Or does this require something else?

use unicode-math package to use opentype math fonts with latex (I'd use luatex rather than xetex unless you have definite need for xetex char classes)

@David Carlisle I am gradually moving away from Math Time Pro II, which has been an old standby, and so far I have explored a number of different technologies to try to get equivalent functionality.  As a hypothetical, suppose I use the Stix 2 fonts with unicode-math.  What I am asking (this has now become a side-topic, so I apologize) specifically is, if I create, say, a 20x20 bracketed matrix, will the brackets be extended to that size by the font MATH table that you mentioned or some functionality of unicode-math?

Can you provide a bit more about your aversion to TikZ? This is almost trivial with TikZ, so I'm curious as to how strong your desire to not use it is.

The Math table (like tfm font metrics) specifies how characters are chained together so specifies for example top bottom and extension glyphs so when the consumer of the font (luatex, or Word or the browser or whatever) asks for a delimiter of a certain size the font technology luaotfload, or harfbuzz or is handed whatever it needs to construct the delimiter of that size (which I only know in principle I have never actually done this for a new font or checked the detailed API in use here) but the principle is clear enough.

eg this display of fontforge showing  vertical constructors in the math table of stix two math. look under file/other-info/math

@AndrewStacey tikz is for planes not math delimiters, surely?

these are not delimiters and this is not a unicode approach, but you might also look at the turnstile package. not because it does what you want, but because it involves constructing extensible symbols for use in maths mode which can then be used in the same way other symbols are used. one advantage or disadvantage (depending) of that type of approach is that it is independent of font and engine. that means the symbols don't always blend in well, but since turnstile is basically the only way to create turnstile symbols, it'provides broad-based and important functionality.

@AndrewStacey I'm a fan, but I still avoid tikz whenever possible. even when using tikz, I avoid tikz when I can. if the OP needs many of these, tikz will (quickly!) slow compilation very markedly. and it is not always straightforward to integrate it into ordinary maths and text. of course, this partly depends on the computing resources you have - l3build can easily crash my terminal, which I assume it doesn't do for the developers who are probably doing much more computationally intensive stuff with it than me.

If not TikZ, then maybe l3draw?

@David Carlisle You mentioned luaotfload and harbuzz, neither of which I am familiar with, but I am assuming they are a layer sitting somewhere between the application and the font (please correct me if I'm wrong).  I know what you said about using LuaTeX instead of XeTeX, but due to a lot of prior work on other ideas, I am somewhat committed to XeTeX at least for the moment.  How does XeTeX load extensible characters?

@MikePugh from the outside it's just like classic tex the font is loaded and \left(xxx\right) asks to draw a big enough ( and the font supplies it, the mechanisms are not visible or adjustable from tex it's just an implementation detail, like asking how A in the input accesses the A glyph from the font. Technically the way the font specifies extensible delimiters differs depending on the font technology involved tfm font metrics or an opentype math table but how tex reads font metrics is just a matter of "read the code" there is nothing accessible from a tex document

incidentally I don't think opentype supports a character that stretches in both directions (and classic tex font tfm certainly does not)

@cfr I'm well aware that there are reasons to avoid TikZ, but also that there are misperceptions of it which mean people say they want to avoid it but actually don't need to. As there was no actual reason given, I was trying to see what the OP's reasons were to judge whether it was worth providing a TikZ solution anyway.

@Andrew Stacy My reasons are more or less outlined in the comments to the answer below.  It is a high-level drawing language (which I use religiously for that purpose) and seems like overkill for a text-based application.  It's not the language itself but the drawing paradigm which seems unsuited for the purpose.  I actually thought initially that what would be required would be aligned with what cfr seems to be suggesting with the turnstile package: writing LaTeX code to painstakingly align various glyphs.  But then I stumbled across the tfm file format and realized there was more to it.

As I said below, TeX was accomplishing this a long time ago, so I didn't think I'd need to reinvent the wheel--except for OpenType advances.  But if, as David Carlisle says, it is impossible to expect the font to extend in perpendicular directions, then I will be relegated to some kind of ad hoc solution anyway.

@AndrewStacey sorry. I knew you know. although I replied to your comment, mine was not really aimed at you.

if you look at, say, the large symbol font knuth designed, you find the individual pieces which fit together to make extensible symbols. also, if you take an afm file, say, and generate font metrics using a programme that produces pl (or, even, vpl) as an intermediate format, you can see some of how things get put together. you can turn a tfm into a pl but that is much less useful, imho. when you convert pl/vpl into tfm all the comments are stripped out, so the human-readable form you get back is much less informative than the one you started with.

One possibility, if you don't want to use TikZ due to its complexity, could be to use the experimental l3draw package:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{l3draw}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\coffin_new:N \l__cornerbracket_contents_coffin
\coffin_new:N \l__cornerbracket_bracket_coffin
\dim_new:N \l__cornerbracket_contents_width_dim
\dim_new:N \l__cornerbracket_contents_height_dim

\dim_new:N \l_cornerbracket_bracket_offset_x_dim
\dim_new:N \l_cornerbracket_bracket_offset_y_dim
\dim_new:N \l_cornerbracket_bracket_tip_length_dim
\dim_new:N \l_cornerbracket_bracket_line_width_dim
\str_new:N \l_cornerbracket_bracket_position_str

\msg_new:nnn { cornerbracket } { unknown-position } { 
    Unknown ~ position ~ value. 
}

\keys_define:nn { cornerbracket } {
    offset ~ x   .dim_set:N = \l_cornerbracket_bracket_offset_x_dim ,
    offset ~ x   .initial:n = { 5pt } ,
    offset ~ y   .dim_set:N = \l_cornerbracket_bracket_offset_y_dim ,
    offset ~ y   .initial:n = { 5pt } ,
    tip ~ length .dim_set:N = \l_cornerbracket_bracket_tip_length_dim ,
    tip ~ length .initial:n = { 2pt } ,
    line ~ width .dim_set:N = \l_cornerbracket_bracket_line_width_dim ,
    line ~ width .initial:n = { \l_draw_default_linewidth_dim } ,
    position     .str_set:N = \l_cornerbracket_bracket_position_str ,
    position     .initial:n = { nw } 
}

\NewDocumentCommand { \cornerbracket } { O{} m } { 
    \keys_set:nn { cornerbracket } {#1}

    \hcoffin_set:Nn \l__cornerbracket_contents_coffin { $#2$ }
    \dim_set:Nn \l__cornerbracket_contents_width_dim 
        { \coffin_wd:N \l__cornerbracket_contents_coffin }
    \dim_set:Nn \l__cornerbracket_contents_height_dim 
        { \coffin_ht:N \l__cornerbracket_contents_coffin +
          \coffin_dp:N \l__cornerbracket_contents_coffin }

    \hcoffin_set:Nn \l__cornerbracket_bracket_coffin {  
        \draw_begin:
            \draw_linewidth:n { \l_cornerbracket_bracket_line_width_dim }
            \str_case_e:nnF { \l_cornerbracket_bracket_position_str } {
                { nw } { 
                    \draw_path_moveto:n { 
                        -\l_cornerbracket_bracket_offset_x_dim +
                        \l_cornerbracket_bracket_tip_length_dim , 
                        -\l_cornerbracket_bracket_offset_y_dim }
                    \draw_path_lineto:n { 
                        -\l_cornerbracket_bracket_offset_x_dim , 
                        -\l_cornerbracket_bracket_offset_y_dim }
                    \draw_path_lineto:n { 
                        -\l_cornerbracket_bracket_offset_x_dim , 
                        \l__cornerbracket_contents_height_dim +
                        \l_cornerbracket_bracket_offset_y_dim }
                    \draw_path_lineto:n { 
                        \l__cornerbracket_contents_width_dim +
                        \l_cornerbracket_bracket_offset_x_dim , 
                        \l__cornerbracket_contents_height_dim +
                        \l_cornerbracket_bracket_offset_y_dim }
                    \draw_path_lineto:n { 
                        \l__cornerbracket_contents_width_dim +
                        \l_cornerbracket_bracket_offset_x_dim , 
                        \l__cornerbracket_contents_height_dim +
                        \l_cornerbracket_bracket_offset_y_dim -
                        \l_cornerbracket_bracket_tip_length_dim }
                } 
                { ne } { 
                    \draw_path_moveto:n { 
                        -\l_cornerbracket_bracket_offset_x_dim ,
                        \l__cornerbracket_contents_height_dim +
                        \l_cornerbracket_bracket_offset_y_dim -
                        \l_cornerbracket_bracket_tip_length_dim }
                    \draw_path_lineto:n { 
                        -\l_cornerbracket_bracket_offset_x_dim , 
                        \l__cornerbracket_contents_height_dim +
                        \l_cornerbracket_bracket_offset_y_dim }
                    \draw_path_lineto:n { 
                        \l__cornerbracket_contents_width_dim +
                        \l_cornerbracket_bracket_offset_x_dim , 
                        \l__cornerbracket_contents_height_dim +
                        \l_cornerbracket_bracket_offset_y_dim }
                    \draw_path_lineto:n { 
                        \l__cornerbracket_contents_width_dim +
                        \l_cornerbracket_bracket_offset_x_dim , 
                        -\l_cornerbracket_bracket_offset_y_dim }
                    \draw_path_lineto:n { 
                        \l__cornerbracket_contents_width_dim +
                        \l_cornerbracket_bracket_offset_x_dim -
                        \l_cornerbracket_bracket_tip_length_dim , 
                        -\l_cornerbracket_bracket_offset_y_dim  }
                } 
                { sw } { 
                    \draw_path_moveto:n { 
                        -\l_cornerbracket_bracket_offset_x_dim +
                        \l_cornerbracket_bracket_tip_length_dim , 
                        \l__cornerbracket_contents_height_dim +
                        \l_cornerbracket_bracket_offset_y_dim }
                    \draw_path_lineto:n { 
                        -\l_cornerbracket_bracket_offset_x_dim , 
                        \l__cornerbracket_contents_height_dim +
                        \l_cornerbracket_bracket_offset_y_dim }
                    \draw_path_lineto:n { 
                        -\l_cornerbracket_bracket_offset_x_dim , 
                        -\l_cornerbracket_bracket_offset_y_dim }
                    \draw_path_lineto:n { 
                        \l__cornerbracket_contents_width_dim +
                        \l_cornerbracket_bracket_offset_x_dim , 
                        -\l_cornerbracket_bracket_offset_y_dim }
                    \draw_path_lineto:n { 
                        \l__cornerbracket_contents_width_dim +
                        \l_cornerbracket_bracket_offset_x_dim , 
                        -\l_cornerbracket_bracket_offset_y_dim +
                        \l_cornerbracket_bracket_tip_length_dim }
                } 
                { se } { 
                    \draw_path_moveto:n { 
                        -\l_cornerbracket_bracket_offset_x_dim +
                        \l_cornerbracket_bracket_tip_length_dim , 
                        -\l_cornerbracket_bracket_offset_y_dim +
                        \l_cornerbracket_bracket_tip_length_dim }
                    \draw_path_lineto:n { 
                        -\l_cornerbracket_bracket_offset_x_dim +
                        \l_cornerbracket_bracket_tip_length_dim , 
                        -\l_cornerbracket_bracket_offset_y_dim }
                    \draw_path_lineto:n { 
                        \l__cornerbracket_contents_width_dim +
                        \l_cornerbracket_bracket_offset_x_dim , 
                        -\l_cornerbracket_bracket_offset_y_dim }
                    \draw_path_lineto:n { 
                        \l__cornerbracket_contents_width_dim +
                        \l_cornerbracket_bracket_offset_x_dim , 
                        \l__cornerbracket_contents_height_dim +
                        \l_cornerbracket_bracket_offset_y_dim }
                    \draw_path_lineto:n { 
                        \l__cornerbracket_contents_width_dim +
                        \l_cornerbracket_bracket_offset_x_dim -
                        \l_cornerbracket_bracket_tip_length_dim , 
                        \l__cornerbracket_contents_height_dim +
                        \l_cornerbracket_bracket_offset_y_dim }
                } 
            } { 
                \msg_warning:nn { cornerbracket } { unknown-position }
            }
            \draw_path_use_clear:n { stroke }
        \draw_end:
    }

    \coffin_join:NnnNnnnn 
        \l__cornerbracket_contents_coffin { vc } { hc } 
        \l__cornerbracket_bracket_coffin { vc } { hc } 
        { 0pt } { 0pt }

    \coffin_typeset:Nnnnn \l__cornerbracket_contents_coffin 
        { l } { H } { 0pt } { 0pt }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

x \(
\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
7 & 8 & 9 
\end{matrix}
\) x

\bigskip

x \(
\cornerbracket{
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    4 & 5 & 6 \\
    7 & 8 & 9  
    \end{matrix}
}
\) x \(
\cornerbracket[position=se]{
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    4 & 5 & 6 \\
    7 & 8 & 9  
    \end{matrix}
}
\) x \(
\cornerbracket[position=nw, line width=2pt, tip length=5pt]{
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    4 & 5 & 6 \\
    7 & 8 & 9  
    \end{matrix}
}
\) x

\end{document}


This is just a first approach. It might need further optimization for use in math mode, especially regarding spacing.

This has the look I am shooting for, to be sure.  I think I may have not explained my aversion to TikZ sufficiently.  I use it all the time--for drawing diagrams, pictures, graphs--even things in 3D.  It is excellent for that purpose.  But it is a high- (not low-) level drawing language and I think it is overkill for text-based applications.  It is that whole approach that I am wary of using here, not specifically TikZ.  If Knuth was able to get resizable delimiters working decades ago, then there are already tried and true methods for doing this and I'm just trying figure out what they are.

The reason I am willing to consider the OpenType approach is because I see the writing on the wall.  Things have been moving in that direction for some time and I have gradually had to adjust how I do things to accomplish the same goals.  Now, I am trying to get a step ahead.

@MikePugh Sure, I understand your high/low-level argument. The above is quite low-level (which explains the long-ish code) and it should be quite light-weight when compiling. And it surely is not as overkill as loading TikZ for just these few lines. I am not a font expert though, so I can't really help with a purely font-based approach.

Probably something similar to \fbox does the trick.
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
%============[adjust margins/layout]====================================
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pagewidth}{}{\pagewidth=\paperwidth}%
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pdfpagewidth}{}%
                                            {\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth}%
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pageheight}{}{\pageheight=\paperheight}%
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pdfpageheight}{}%
                                          {\pdfpageheight=\paperheight}%
\oddsidemargin=1.5cm
\marginparsep=.2\oddsidemargin
\marginparwidth=.4\oddsidemargin
\textwidth=\paperwidth
\advance\textwidth by -2\oddsidemargin
\advance\oddsidemargin by -1in
\evensidemargin=\oddsidemargin
\textheight=\paperheight
\topmargin=1.5cm
\headheight=0ex
\headsep=0ex
\advance\textheight by -2\topmargin
\advance\topmargin by -1in
{\normalfont
 \setbox\csname @tempboxa\endcsname\hbox{0123456789}%
 \global\footskip=\dimexpr .5cm -.5\dp\csname @tempboxa\endcsname
                                +.5\ht\csname @tempboxa\endcsname\relax
}%
{\normalfont
 \setbox\csname @tempboxa\endcsname\hbox{%
    0123456789ANCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz%
 }%
 \global\topskip=\ht\csname @tempboxa\endcsname
}%
\pagestyle{plain}%
\parindent=0ex
%==================[eof margin-adjustments]=============================


\usepackage{amsmath}
\newbox\scratchbox

\makeatletter
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@gobbletoexclam{\long\def\UD@gobbletoexclam#1!{}}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@@MapCorner{%
  \long\def\UD@@MapCorner#1!Top Left!Top Right!Bottom Left!Bottom Right!#2#3!!!!{#2}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@MapCorner[6]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@gobbletoexclam#1!}%
  {%
    \UD@@MapCorner
    !#1!Top Right!Bottom Left!Bottom Right!{#3}% Top Left
    !Top Left!#1!Bottom Left!Bottom Right!{#4}% Top Right
    !Top Left!Top Right!#1!Bottom Right!{#5}% Bottom Left
    !Top Left!Top Right!Bottom Left!#1!{#6}% Bottom Right
    !Top Left!Top Right!Bottom Left!Bottom Right!{#2}% Corners
    !!!!%
  }{#2}% s.th. else with ! / Corners
}%
\newcommand\matrixcorners[2]{%
  \vtop{%
    \setbox\scratchbox\vbox{%
      \hrule height \dimexpr\cornerlinethickness\relax
      \hbox{%
        \vrule width \dimexpr\cornerlinethickness\relax
        \kern\dimexpr\cornershift\relax
        \vtop{%
          \vbox{%
            \kern\dimexpr\cornershift\relax
            \hbox{%
              $\begin{matrix}#2\end{matrix}$%
            }%
          }%
          \kern\dimexpr\cornershift\relax
        }%
        \kern\dimexpr\cornershift\relax
        \vrule width \dimexpr\cornerlinethickness\relax
      }%
    }%
    \vbox{%
      \hbox to \wd\scratchbox{%
          %Top line
          \UD@MapCorner{#1}{%
            \vbox{\hrule height \dimexpr\cornerlinethickness\relax width \dimexpr\cornerticklength+\cornerlinethickness\relax}%
            \hfill
            \vbox{\hrule height \dimexpr\cornerlinethickness\relax width \dimexpr\cornerticklength+\cornerlinethickness\relax}%
          }{%
            \vrule width \wd\scratchbox height \dimexpr\cornerlinethickness\relax
          }{%
            \vrule width \wd\scratchbox height \dimexpr\cornerlinethickness\relax
          }{%
            \vbox{\hrule height \dimexpr\cornerlinethickness\relax width \dimexpr\cornerticklength+\cornerlinethickness\relax}%
            \hfill
          }{%
            \hfill
            \vbox{\hrule height \dimexpr\cornerlinethickness\relax width \dimexpr\cornerticklength+\cornerlinethickness\relax}%
          }%
      }%
      \hrule height0pt
      \setbox\scratchbox=\hbox{%
        \vrule height \dimexpr\cornerlinethickness\relax
        \kern\dimexpr\cornershift\relax
        \vtop{%
          \vbox{%
            \kern\dimexpr\cornershift\relax
            \hbox{%
              $\begin{matrix}#2\end{matrix}$%
            }%
          }%
          \kern\dimexpr\cornershift\relax
        }%
        \kern\dimexpr\cornershift\relax
        \vrule height \dimexpr\cornerlinethickness\relax
      }%
      \hbox{%
        \lower\dp\scratchbox\vbox to \dimexpr\ht\scratchbox+\dp\scratchbox{%
          %Left line
          \UD@MapCorner{#1}{%
            \hbox{\vrule width \dimexpr\cornerlinethickness\relax height \dimexpr\cornerticklength\relax}%
            \vfill
            \hbox{\vrule width \dimexpr\cornerlinethickness\relax height \dimexpr\cornerticklength\relax}%
          }{%
            \hrule height \dimexpr\ht\scratchbox+\dp\scratchbox width \dimexpr\cornerlinethickness\relax
          }{%
            \hbox{\vrule width \dimexpr\cornerlinethickness\relax height \dimexpr\cornerticklength\relax}%
            \vfill
          }{%
            \hrule height \dimexpr\ht\scratchbox+\dp\scratchbox width \dimexpr\cornerlinethickness\relax
          }{%
            \vfill
            \hbox{\vrule width \dimexpr\cornerlinethickness\relax height \dimexpr\cornerticklength\relax}%
          }%
        }%
        \kern\dimexpr\cornershift\relax
        \vtop{%
          \vbox{%
            \kern\dimexpr\cornershift\relax
            \hbox{%
              $\begin{matrix}#2\end{matrix}$%
            }%
          }%
          \kern\dimexpr\cornershift\relax
        }%
        \kern\dimexpr\cornershift\relax
        \lower\dp\scratchbox\vbox to \dimexpr\ht\scratchbox+\dp\scratchbox{%
          %Right line
          \UD@MapCorner{#1}{%
            \hbox{\vrule width \dimexpr\cornerlinethickness\relax height \dimexpr\cornerticklength\relax}%
            \vfill
            \hbox{\vrule width \dimexpr\cornerlinethickness\relax height \dimexpr\cornerticklength\relax}%
          }{%
            \hbox{\vrule width \dimexpr\cornerlinethickness\relax height \dimexpr\cornerticklength\relax}%
            \vfill
          }{%
            \hrule height \dimexpr\ht\scratchbox+\dp\scratchbox width \dimexpr\cornerlinethickness\relax
          }{%
            \vfill
            \hbox{\vrule width \dimexpr\cornerlinethickness\relax height \dimexpr\cornerticklength\relax}%
          }{%
            \hrule height \dimexpr\ht\scratchbox+\dp\scratchbox width \dimexpr\cornerlinethickness\relax
          }%
        }%
      }%
    }%
    \hrule height0pt
    \hbox to \wd\scratchbox{%
      %Bottom line
      \UD@MapCorner{#1}{%
        \vbox{\hrule height \dimexpr\cornerlinethickness\relax width \dimexpr\dimexpr\cornerticklength\relax+\cornerlinethickness\relax}%
        \hfill
        \vbox{\hrule height \dimexpr\cornerlinethickness\relax width \dimexpr\dimexpr\cornerticklength\relax+\cornerlinethickness\relax}%
      }{%
        \vbox{\hrule height \dimexpr\cornerlinethickness\relax width \dimexpr\dimexpr\cornerticklength\relax+\cornerlinethickness\relax}%
        \hfill
      }{%
        \hfill
        \vbox{\hrule height \dimexpr\cornerlinethickness\relax width \dimexpr\dimexpr\cornerticklength\relax+\cornerlinethickness\relax}%
      }{%
        \vrule width \wd\scratchbox height \dimexpr\cornerlinethickness\relax
      }{%
        \vrule width \wd\scratchbox height \dimexpr\cornerlinethickness\relax
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\newcommand\cornerticklength{2mm}%
\newcommand\cornerlinethickness{\fboxrule}%
\newcommand\cornershift{\fboxsep}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\matrixcorners{Corners}{%
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  0 & 2 & 4 \\
  1 & 1 & 0 \\
  3 & 4 & 2
}%
AAA%
\matrixcorners{Top Left}{%
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  0 & 2 & 4 \\
  1 & 1 & 0 \\
  3 & 4 & 2
}%
AAA%
\matrixcorners{Top Right}{%
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  0 & 2 & 4 \\
  1 & 1 & 0 \\
  3 & 4 & 2
}%
AAA%
\matrixcorners{Bottom Left}{%
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  0 & 2 & 4 \\
  1 & 1 & 0 \\
  3 & 4 & 2
}%
AAA%
\matrixcorners{Bottom Right}{%
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  0 & 2 & 4 \\
  1 & 1 & 0 \\
  3 & 4 & 2
}%
AAA\fbox{$\left(\begin{matrix}1 & 2 & 3 \\ 0 & 2 & 4 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 3 & 4 & 2\end{matrix}\right)$}%
AAA\fbox{$\begin{matrix}1 & 2 & 3 \\ 0 & 2 & 4 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 3 & 4 & 2\end{matrix}$}%AAA

\bigskip

\renewcommand\cornerticklength{4mm}%
\renewcommand\cornerlinethickness{3\fboxrule}%
\renewcommand\cornershift{2\fboxsep}

\noindent
\matrixcorners{Corners}{%
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  0 & 2 & 4 \\
  1 & 1 & 0 \\
  3 & 4 & 2
}%
AAA%
\matrixcorners{Top Left}{%
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  0 & 2 & 4 \\
  1 & 1 & 0 \\
  3 & 4 & 2
}%
AAA%
\matrixcorners{Top Right}{%
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  0 & 2 & 4 \\
  1 & 1 & 0 \\
  3 & 4 & 2
}%
AAA%
\matrixcorners{Bottom Left}{%
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  0 & 2 & 4 \\
  1 & 1 & 0 \\
  3 & 4 & 2
}%
AAA%
\matrixcorners{Bottom Right}{%
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  0 & 2 & 4 \\
  1 & 1 & 0 \\
  3 & 4 & 2
}%
AAA

\end{document}


